# DataTables reload custom ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

DataTables has [3 options for using ajax](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax): **url**, **ajax object**, and **custom function**.

I'm using the **custom function** option, and I'm trying to figure out how to set a different ajax function after the DataTables creation.

I've seen [`ajax.reload`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()), but this only seem to work with the **url** ajax option. Any idea how to reset a custom function and reload the data?

---

As an example, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
// Create DataTable
dt = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
   ajax: function(input, callback, settings) {...}
});

// Update Ajax with a new function call
function updateAjax() {
    // reload with new ajax function.
    dt.ajax.reload(function(input, callback, settings) {...})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think tfidelis answer will work too, but I ended up going a different route:

```
// Define variable globally
var myGlobalState = ...;

// Create DataTable
var dt = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
  ajax: function(input, callback, settings) {
    doSomething(myGlobalState);
  }
});

// Update Ajax when myGlobalState changes
function updateMyGlobalState() {
  myGlobalState = ...;
  dt.ajax.reload();
}
```

Comment: I understand. So, please, let us know if it works too.

Answer (score 1):

let me ask... why do you need to reset your ajax function? I think you will need that only when you create dataTable again. if is this case, just create it again with your new ajax function:

```
// Update Ajax with a new function call
function updateAjax() {
  dt = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
    ajax: function(input, callback, settings) {...}
    });
}
```

If it is not the case, could you explain the situation for me?

Comment: I'm manually querying a local database, and I want to reload whenever the database changes. I think your solution will work; however, I decided to go another way, which is to have the ajax function reference a 'global' variable of the database. Then, whenever the DB changes, I just call dt.ajax.reload()

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work unless you set the [destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option to `true`